# Open a file with a java application

Tags: java

I made a text editor in java. It has a `FileExplorer` class which allows me to read and write to a file. Now I would like to know how I could open said file (text.txt) with my editor application from outside my application. Basically when I double-click on the file (text.txt) it should start my application and pass some variables(like name and path). The application is a .jar file.
I am not going to bother anyone to go through the 2k lines of code, so I won't post it in here. But it is just a `JTextPane` in a `JFrame` and a `PrintWriter`/`BufferedReader` reading and writing to the file.

PS: should preferably work cross-platform.
Thanks

Comment: This will depend on your OS and require an ad-hoc solution, different for each platform. For Windows you can take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with). Not a good question for SO in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Why do you think that this is an inappropriate question for SO?

Comment: I agree with Mena - this does not sound like a programming problem. It's a question of configuring the OS to use your program for the default open action.

Comment: @Haeri you're welcome. Why this question doesn't look like SO material is because of what Ted Hopp said: it's not about programming, it's about setting the right program to open a specific file type in [any] OS. You probably also want to narrow it down to each OS or just do the research - plenty of material to look for already there.

Comment: @Mena OK. Well I was hoping that Java had something like: if you set an application as a standard application to open a file it could feed some magic to main(String[] args)... 
Hmm I was told that I should use java for cross-platform compatibility but I am hitting many platform walls lately.

Comment: @Haeri Java is cross-platform compatible, but what you are trying here is to tell your OS to do something, i.e. open this type of file with this program. So of course, while we can assume your program will run on any OS supporting Java, it will depend on the actual OS on how to tell it to prefer your program to the default text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not about java. It is about mapping files to specific application using you OS tools.

If you are on Windows you have to map extension `*.txt` to your application. Take a look on [this article](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows%2Fdesktop%2Fcc144104%2528v%3Dvs.85%2529.aspx&ei=9vB1VPelHajlywOonIHIBQ&usg=AFQjCNHGGsKDTHONczpTlIV4AsSNN1cwPA&bvm=bv.80642063,d.bGQ&cad=rja) for details.

Please note that your application must accept file path in command line. 
To make association easier I'd recommend you to writer batch file that runs your application and also accepts file name in command line. Then you just have to associate your batch file with `*.txt` extension.

If you are on Linux association technique depends on your flavor, but you can google it. Obviously you will have to create shell script instead of batch file.

EDIT

Actually your question is mostly about installation process. There are a lot of installation tools that can do this work for you. Some of the tools are even cross platform (I can remember "install anywhere"). There are both commercial and free tools that do this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is there no existing framework I could use? I mean I can't be the first one asking for such an obvious functionality.